# QR if statement?

Tags: android, qr-code

I was wondering if anyone has solved this problem. I want to scan a QR code from my android phone that will ultimately launch an Android App. If the app exists, the app is launched with some unique information. If the app doesn't exist then it takes the user the marketplace to download the app. Can this be done?

Any help will greatly be appreciated :)

Comment: How are you planning to associate a specific QR code with a particular app?  To launch an app, you need to have the fully qualified class name of the app.  QR code for an app usually contains encoded URL on the market for that app.  You somehow need to associate a particular market URL with a specific class name.

Comment: How can you scan QR in first place without application ? No. not possible

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do this, but I guess you could encode the app's market url in the QR code. By that, the market is opened if the app is not installed. However, if it's installed, you could use an Intent-Filter in your app to catch that Url (if it's possible, I honestly don't know)

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can write an app that can do that. [Barcode Scanner](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android) actually does some of the things you want (e.g. opening the market from a code), it's [open source](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/), if you need some samples take a look there. The project also has a library that you can use to scan QR-/barcodes.

*Keep in mind that a QR-code is nothing else than a String in a machine-readable format.* You can encode a package name in a code and scan that. When you successfully did that, just test if the app with that package name is present on the device. If yes, run it via an `Intent` *(you can use [`PackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getLaunchIntentForPackage%28java.lang.String%29) for that)*. If not, link to the market page via `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` with a market url. You may encode some extras into the QR-codes, depending on which size you choose for these.

The benefit from the package name only is that there are many codes already out there that link to the android market site of a certain app. Their format is

```
market://search?q=pname:com.example
```

As you can see, theres already a packagename included (here `com.example`).
You can parse and use it. If you want extras, you have to encode your own qr-codes though.