# Android QR check if app installed

Tags: android, if-statement, qr-code

I'm scanning QR code (where specific data is coded) with QR scanner. If my app is installed on the device, the app is launched. If the app doesn't installed then it takes the user the marketplace to download the app. I've searched a lot on internet and only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7263198/qr-if-statement) question.

Here's activity from manifest file which is called when QR code is scanned

```
<activity android:name=".map.TestQrOpenActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data android:scheme="uniqueapp"/>
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and here's the string which is coded in my QR code

```
uniqueapp://myData
```

and that works perfectly if app installed in device, but if it's not installed I need to go to google play and download it basically
if app exist open `uniqueapp://myData` else open `market://details?id=com.my.package.name`
So is this possible? (I don't whant to write my own scanner)

Comment: How can a user scan a QR code with your app while your app isn't installed?

Comment: @Gerald Schneider I'm scanniing QR code with different app (QR scanner)

Comment: Have u checked my answer yet, it does just what u want, first give your path as link, second give the appstore url

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 public static boolean intentIsAvailable(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
   final PackageManager mgr = ctx.getPackageManager();
   List<ResolveInfo> list =
      mgr.queryIntentActivities(intent, 
         PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
   return list.size() > 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work if my app is not installed (I don't want to write my own QR reader)

Comment: Ohh K.. Now I got you question.. Wait a min

Comment: I believe that what you are trying is simply impossible because Logic you want to execute cant be there in QR Code.. There has to be some brain in Reading QR Code App that it should redirect to Market.. One way I feel this can be achieved if you have Web Hosted... But that is long way.. And I am sure you can achieve this with that option

Answer (score 1):

**Reframing the question:**

From what I'm reading, I think you want to accomplish the following:

1. Read my QR code with my app
2. Read my QR code with any other QR reader
3. Always send the QR data to my app or my website.
4. If my app is not installed, help the user get my app installed.

I think you solve all four of the use cases I'm describing with app links.

**Android App Links:**

http://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

With an app link you could put your URL in front, and have your app intercept it if the app is installed, and if not installed, android would simply send people to your website.  Once they're on your website, you could tell them they need to install your app.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is the solution for u:

[appurl](http://www.appurl.io/)

> **Note:** The app will always try the first url then fallback to the second url. For example under "iOS - iPhone" if you wanted to open the tweetbot app you would add tweetbot:// to the first text field then add the iTunes store url to the second text field. When a user taps on the link if they are on their iPhone it will check to see if the user has tweetbot installed, if not it will take them to the iTunes store.

It generates a **URL** and a **QR Code** 
Hope this is what u need.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [ZXing Android Embedded](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded).

This way you don't have to write your own scanner and the user doesn't have to install anything else.